# Why do comparisons in QGIS 2.4.0 Raster Calculator return -3.40282e+38 aka no_data?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-2.4

I tried to use comparisons as conditional statements in QGIS 2.4.0 raster calculator.

My statement is:

```
(a < 230) * 230 + (a >= 230) * a
```

The expected result is raster **a** with all values lower than 230 replaced by 230.

What I get instead is a raster with nan and 3.40282e+38.

Upon further investigation I found that the comparison returns either 1 or nan / -3.40282e+38. Why is it not returning 1 or 0? What am I doing wrong? How can I build conditional statements with the raster calculator?

Comment: Your statement seems fine, it may be a problem with the raster layer itself. How was your raster created?

Comment: I got point elevation data in some weird custom Japanese CRS which I interpolated via Raster->Analysis->Grid, then warped into WGS 84 and clipped to get a clean raster.
[This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108641/qgis-raster-calculator-need-values-to-be-set-to-0-instead-of-no-data) hints at a workaround using Saga or ASCII rasters. Still I am curious why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you manually change the CRS **before** you interpolate and clip?

Comment: Sorry Joseph, I forgot to answer this because I found another solution for my general problem. But it might be good to know that this is resolved as of QGIS 2.12.0. Everything works as expected. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Don't worry about it buddy, you're only over a year late! :). But glad you got it working, you should post how you solved it as an **answer** to close this question off.