# Raster calculator : How to make 0 + NoData = 0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, qgis-2.10

I have a point data layer (vector) that I converted to a raster layer. I want to replace the NoData value (between each raster point) in the point raster layer by 0. So, I made a background raster layer (value = 0).

My plan was to add the background layer of 0 to the point raster layer, but as we can see in the [+ (Addition)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005m000000mv000000) tool page, a number (0) + NoData = NoData.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3, but I also have access to QGIS 2.10.

EDIT : I saw the [QGIS Raster Calculator: Need values to be set to 0 instead of no data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108641/qgis-raster-calculator-need-values-to-be-set-to-0-instead-of-no-data) question, but I can't find the "Reclassify grid cells" tool. I just have "Reclassify grid values".

[image]

Comment: Use con( isnull( raster),0,raster)

Comment: The answer that @FelixIP points to is supposed to be used in the Raster Calculator from ArcGIS. It works wonderfully. See http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34932 for more info.

Comment: @FelixIP Works great! Can you add it as an anwser so I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and fastest way to replace NODATA with something else, is map algebra/raster calculator:

[image]

It works on float and integer rasters. It is a good idea to specify type of output raster explicitly, using built-in functions Int or Float

Answer (score 1):

The Reclassify tool in ArcMap 10.3 (Spatial Analyst > Reclass > Reclassify) enables you to reclassify No Data to another value. Now, this might not work for you if you have No Data values in your output sum image that you *don't* want to reclassify as 0. There are ways around this issue, but if you are OK with turning all of your No Data value to 0 then the Reclassify is a straightforward way to solve this.

Comment: I already thought of that, but the problem is that I only want to change the No Data and leave the rest intact. My point data has a lot of unique values and Reclassify works in range.

Comment: Ok, here is an idea for a work around: Add a field to your point data that indicates it is an instance of summing Zero with No Data. You could do this with spatial join if you are familiar with that tool. Then, select those points by attributes (e.g. WHERE '0 Plus No Data' = TRUE) and then run the Reclassify tool.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the nodata value in your raster, then remove the nodata flag. This is probably fastest with gdal. For example, if your nodata value is -9999:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 input.tif output.tif
gdal_edit.py -a_nodata -9999 output.tif
```

`gdalwarp` has rewritten all your nodata cells to value 0, and changed the nodata flag to 0. `gdal_edit.py` has changed the nodata flag back to -9999, leaving the pixels untouched. The 0 pixels are now valid.