# Adding Raster by raster calculator gives no values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I`m trying to add several raster files to one (like a merge). I tried using the raster calculator (in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and in QGIS 2.8.1 and QGIS 2.10). Anything I do leads to rasterfiles which have only NULL-Values.

Every raster has the same extent, same projection type and pixelsize.
All rasters are in floating point and have NULL-Values.
I tried many things but mainly I just tried to add them 
like:

```
Raster1 + Raster 2 + Raster 3 and so on.
```

I also tried the `melt` function in QGIS and the `GRIDsum` function in SAGA. It must be a problem with my data but I don´t have an idea what could be wrong.
Anyone an idea what I could try?

Edit: Also I should mention, that there is a NULL value for every pixel in at least on of the rasters used.

Comment: Any math involving a null results in null. Those will have to be converted to 0 or ignored.

Comment: I understand. Thx. But I find it a bit strange, that nothing plus something euals nothing.....

Comment: It might help to think of it as null isn't nothing, it's *I don't know*. Zero is nothing. Null is unknown, no data - it could be an unknown value more or less than zero. And unknown plus anything is still unknown.

Comment: I see. But how can I ever change that than?

Comment: It really depends on your data. When talking about null values in rasters, they are often called nodata cells as well as null values. We have a number of questions on dealing with null/nodata in rasters. If converting the null values to zero works for your case (there are implications for results when treating a null as zero - sometimes it can skew or alter them depending on the data), take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167606/ which is just one of several questions about doing so. Some spatial analyst tools simply ignore nodata values, or can be set to do so.